# `Last` command not working or am I not logged in?

Tags: users, login, last

`Last` command does not show me as logged in. What should I do? I want to run the last command to see all users logged in on a specific date, but the output of `last` is `wtmp begins` followed by a date.

Comment: Welcome, could you add the command used to your question.

Comment: @GAD3R Hi! Iam simply typing `last` withot any options. When I enter `who am i` it shows me my name, as if I were logged in. Nonetheless by simply entering `last` it does not show me my name followed by the other relevant details expected.